# Showing data Roles Spatie from eloquent relations get error in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i want to showing data from relation of User and Roles Spatie. But i've got error doesn't exist collections. Here is my code :

Model :

```
   <?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, HasRoles;
```

Controller :

```
   public function index()
    {
       $data_user = User::with('roles')->get();
    
       return view('role.role', [
         'data_user' => $data_user
       ]);
    }
```

role.blade.php :

```
             <table class="table-hover table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">No.</th>
                        <th scope="col">User</th>
                        <th scope="col">Email</th>
                        <th scope="col">Role</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                @foreach ($data_user as $du)
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td scope="row">{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $du->name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $du->email }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $du->roles->name }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                @endforeach
            </table>
```

Error:
Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `roles` relation is a collection of roles since the package allows a user to have multiple roles. So you cannot access the property `name` on the collection.

You need to get an individual role from the collection, for example

```
{{ optional($du->roles->first())->name }}
```

**Edit**

If you wish to show multiple roles, you could implode them

```php
{{ $du->roles->implode('name', ', ') }}
```

If you wish to make it neater, you could write a loop to generate badges. Here's a simple example using bootstrap

```php
<td>
@foreach($du->roles as $role)
    <span class="badge bg-primary">{{ $role->name }}</span>
@endforeach
</td>
```

Comment: ah i see. Yes, it work. Thank you for your help. But what if a user have multiple roles? how to show them?